# How to filter manage categories listing

Tags: plugin-development

I'm successfully using the function below to trim the length of my category descriptions when viewing the manage category screen (thanks Rarst).

Suppose I want to remove children of the "uncategorized" category from this listing. Would I simply insert a check in the for loop below to skip over those child items?

UPDATE: With Rarst's tip on using unset(), I've amended the code below with the correct bits to remove specific categories from the manage categories listing...

```
//Clean up description summaries on Category manage edit table
add_action( 'admin_head-edit-tags.php', 'admin_edit_tags' );
function admin_edit_tags() 
{
  add_filter( 'get_terms', 'admin_trim_category_description', 10, 2 );
}
function admin_trim_category_description( $terms, $taxonomies ) 
{
if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] )return $terms;
foreach( $terms as $key=>$term )
{
$terms[$key]->description = strip_tags(substr( $term->description, 0, 75 ))."...";
//new bits here
if($terms[$key]->term_id == 1){unset($terms[$key]);}
}
return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `$terms` contains all terms that are retrieved from database for display so whatever changes you make will cascade upwards to interface.

One issue I am not sure about if that will affect pagination of results in this case.

Comment: thanks again. After re-reading my question I can see that it might not be clear that I'm asking to remove the entire category from the loop, not just skip over trimming the description. Does that make sense? Any clues on how I might except a specific category, by id, from getting written to the grid listing?

Comment: @Scott B yes, I understood your question. As I said `$terms` contains all categories retrieved, so in that loop you check `$term` for a match to unwanted category and do `unset($terms[$key]);` on match. I cautiously think it should work. Do you want me to write out code for you?

Comment: I see now why you were concerned about pagination. I'll need to somehow hook into the pagination routine so that it does not include the categories I'm removing from its page count. Otherwise, as I think you were hinting at, the pagination count will definitely be off.